# Why does a single NAIP 2015 tile have both leaf-off and leaf-on conditions?

Tags: orthophoto, naip

**Image acquired at https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/ with the following criteria:**

[image]

[image]

**Within tile border of leaf-off to leaf-on conditions:**

[image]

Comment: Could you please edit your post to describe where you acquired the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NAIP imagery is supposed to be collected in leaf-on conditions. What you may be seeing are adjacent plane swaths that were collected during different time frames (late spring vs. mid-summer). Swaths are merged together before being packaged as quarter-quads. If you received a shapefile with your imagery it should contain swath features with the collection dates.

[Disclaimer: I work for USDA, but am not involved in the NAIP acquisition process]

Comment: Thanks for this info. It makes sense, given that the two conditions (leaf-off vs. leaf-on) are certainly from different dates. No shapefile was delivered with the imagery unfortunately, so the only date is the "acquisition date" for the entire tile – 06/20/2015. It sounds like this is just part of the NAIP acquisition, and while the imagery is intended to be leaf-on, there is no guarantee.